# how can I create connections among three linux-based machines?

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a launch file that basically connects a Jetson TX1 and a Raspberry Pi 3 witha ubuntu host machine. And I need to configure all three machines such that, when `roscore` runs in the host, it will make connections to the other two boards.

As far as hardware setup is concerned, there is an ethernet-based connection between my linux desktop (ubuntu 14.04) and the jetson tx1 (ubuntu 16.04). The raspberry pi 3 is connected to the jetson board via the USB-3.0-to-Ethernet adapter (AX11789).

Following the hardware setup, the software setup is done. At first, the `/etc/network/interface` file in my desktop is edited as follows:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 iface static
address 192.168.1.42
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.26
```

Then in my jetson,

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.26
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Because it seems correct that the jetson be configured as a gateway (router), the ip address of the jetson should be used as a gateway address in both the desktop and the pi board. So in the pi board,

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.102
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.26
```

After this, the `ping` requests between the desktop and the jetson as well as between the jetson and the pi work perfectly, but the `ping` request between the desktop and the pi board does not work, stating `Ping from 192.168.1.102: Destination host unreachable`.

Is there any critical information or step I am missing in this case? It may probably be due to the configuration with the Ethernet-to-usb adapter, but I'm not 100% certain about this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273879/how-can-i-create-connections-among-three-linux-based-machines?/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
Although you intend to use this for a ROS applcation, this is really more of a networking/Linux setup question. You will most likely get better answers faster if you ask it on stackoverflow or some other forum that deals with Linux configuration issues directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @gvdhoorn mentioned, your question is not directly related to ROS, but here are my two cents:

Your TX1 has two network interfaces (Ethernet and USB-to-Ethernet Adapter) that are isolated from each other. This means that even though you are using IP addresses on the same range for both adapters, they *don't know* how to pass messages from one interface to the other. You would think that setting the "gateway address" to the TX1 IP would be enough but it doesn't work like that.

What you are looking for is called "interface bridging". This link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge will give you further information.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-23**:
It would be far less configuration to just connect all three computers to a small network switch.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2017-10-23**:
Indeed!!